# How to build a drop down dymic using ajax in Grails 3.0

Tags: grails

How I can build a drop down with dynamic load using Ajax? For example a drop down of states execute a method in onchange option for load a other drop down of cities.
I try use the tag g:remoteFunction but it does not exist in the version 3.0.

Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

The g:remoteFunction taglib for Grails 3 is in the [ajax-tags](https://bintray.com/grails/plugins/ajax-tags/view) plugin. The Maven artifact is **org.grails.plugins:ajax-tags:1.0.0**